# Having issues tying together basic javascript chat page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the skeleton of a chat page but am having issues tying it all together. What I'm trying to do is have messages sent to the server whenever the user clicks send, and also, for the messages shown to update every 3 seconds. Any insights, tips, or general comments would be much appreciated.

Issues right now:

1. When I fetch, I append the `<ul class="messages"></ul>` but don't want to reappend messages I've already fetched.
2. Make sure my chatSend is working correctly but if I run chatSend, then chatFetch, I don't retrieve the message I sent.

```
var input1 = document.getElementById('input1'), sendbutton =     document.getElementById('sendbutton');

function IsEmpty(){ 
if (input1.value){
sendbutton.removeAttribute('disabled');
} else {
sendbutton.setAttribute('disabled', '');
 }
}

input1.onkeyup = IsEmpty;


function chatFetch(){
  $.ajax({
      url: "https://api.parse.com/1/classes/chats",
      dataType: "json",
      method: "GET",
      success: function(data){

            $(".messages").clear();

            for(var key in data) {
                for(var i in data[key]){
                  console.log(data[key][i])
                  $(".messages").append("<li>"+data[key][i].text+"</li>");
                }
            }    

      }
  })
}

function chatSend(){

$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "https://api.parse.com/1/classes/chats",
       data: JSON.stringify({text: $('input1.draft').val()}), 
       success:function(message){


       }
  })
}



chatFetch();
$("#sendbutton").on('click',chatSend());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like a pretty good project for [Knockout.js](http://knockoutjs.com/), especially if you want to make sure you're not re-appending messages you've already sent. Since the library was meant in no small part for that sort of thing, I think it would make sense to leverage it to its full potential. So let's say that your API already takes care of limiting how many messages have come back, searching for the right messages, etc., and focus strictly on the UI. We can start with our Javascript view model of a chat message...

```
function IM(msg) {
    var self = this;

    self.username = ko.observable();
    self.message = ko.observable();
    self.timestamp = ko.observable();
}
```

This is taking a few liberties and assuming that you get back an IM object which has the name of the user sending the message, and the content, as well as a timestamp for the message. Probably not too far fetched to hope you have access to these data elements, right? Moving on to the large view model encapsulating your IMs...

```
function vm() {
    var self = this;

    self.messages = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.message = ko.observable(new IM());

    self.setup = function () {
        self.chatFetch();

        self.message().username([user current username] || '');            
    };

    self.chatFetch = function () {
        $.getJSON("https://api.parse.com/1/classes/chats", function(results){
            for(var key in data) {
                // parse your incoming data to get whatever elements you
                // can matching the IM view model here then assign it as
                // per these examples as closely as possible

                var im = new IM();

                im.username(data[key][i].username || '');
                im.message(data[key][i].message || '');
                im.timestamp(data[key][i].message || '');

                // the ([JSON data] || '') defaults the property to an
                // empty strings so it fails gracefully when no data is
                // available to assign to it

                self.messages.push(im);
            }
        });
    };
}
```

All right, so we have out Javascript models which will update the screen via bindings (more on that in a bit) and we're getting and populating data. But how do we update and send IMs? Well, remember that `self.message` object? We get to use it now.

```
function vm() {

    // ... our setup and initial get code

    self.chatSend = function () {
        var data = { 
            'user': self.message().username(),
            'text': self.message().message(),
            'time': new Date() 
        };

        $.post("https://api.parse.com/1/classes/chats", data, function(result) {
            // do whatever you want with the results, if anything
        });

        // now we update our current messages and load new ones

        self.chatFetch();
    };
}
```

All right, so how do we keep track of all of this? Through the magic of bindings. Well, it's not magic, it's pretty intense Javascript inside Knockout.js that listens for changes and the updates the elements accordingly, but you don't have to worry about that. You can just worry about your HTML which should look like this...

```
<div id="chat">
    <ul data-bind="foreach: messages">
        <li>
            <span data-bind="text: username"></span> : 
            <span data-bind="text: message"></span> [ 
            <span data-bind="text: timestamp"></span> ]
        </li>
    </ul>        
</div>
<div id="chatInput">
    <input data-bind="value: message" type="text" placeholder="message..." />
    <button data-bind="click: $root.chatSend()">Send</button>
<div>
```

Now for the final step to populate your bindings and keep them updated, is to call your view model and its methods...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var imVM = new vm();

    // perform your initial search and setup
    imVM.setup();

    // apply the bindings and hook it all together
    ko.applyBindings(imVM.messages, $('#chat')[0]);
    ko.applyBindings(imVM.message, $('#chatInput')[0]);

    // and now update the form every three seconds
    setInterval(function() { imVM.chatFetch(); }, 3000);
});
```

So this should give you a pretty decent start on a chat system in an HTML page. I'll leave the validation, styling, and prettifying as an exercise to the programmer...